# How to send sockets for specific clients for IOS as a client.

Tags: ios, node.js, sockets, socket.io

For IOS I have the following code:

```
var socket: SocketIOClient!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: NSURL(string: "http://localhost:3000")! as URL)
    socket.connect()


    socket.on("general") { (_, _) in

        print(123)

    }





}
```

And in NodeJS, I have this:

```
 io.on('connection', function(socket){ 

 socket.emit('general', "somerandomthing")

 });
```

This works fine as it is. However, then I tried to simulate sending messages to specific clients. I did it by replacing

```
 socket.emit('general', "somerandomthing")
```

to

```
 socket.to(socket.id).emit('general', "somerandomthing")
```

It doesnt work anymore If i do that. It probably doesn't make sense, but I can't find any docs that relate specific sockets between an ios client and a server

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
socket.to(socket.id).emit('general', 'somerandomthing')
```

You should do this:

```
io.to(socket.id).emit('general', 'somerandomthing')
```

---

Complete Code:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){ 

  io.to(socket.id).emit('general', 'somerandomthing')

});
```